# How to make a plot

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, plot

Write a script that asks for an integer (n) and then computes the following based on the value of the integer: While the value of n is greater than 1, replace the integer with half of its value (n/2) if the integer is even. Otherwise, replace the integer with three times its value, plus 1 (3*n + 1).
Make provision to count the number of values in (or the length of) the sequence that results.
Example calculation: If n = 10, the sequence of integers is 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 and so the length is 6.

((Make a plot of the length of the sequence that occurs as a function of the integers from 2 to 30. For example, when n = 10, the length is 6 while for n = 15, the length is 17. Is there any pattern? Is there any integer for which the sequence does not terminate?))

Hi,

how I can plot this if I have a function(calculate) and the output is the length

```
for i=2:30 

p = calculate(i)

plot(i,p)

end
```

is that correct ??

Comment: You tell us.  Did your sequence of commands produce the plot you expected ?

Answer (score 1):

You should really just run it and see, but you have options to make it work:

1. Store each `p` generated in the loop, and `plot` after the loop.
2. Plot each point (not connected with lines) inside the loop with `plot` and `hold on`.

This is fundamental.  Read the [plot documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html), *please*.

Comment: Ummm ok I just want more explain because I don't understand your point